# where did the git app get installed on my mac

Tags: git, macos, github, finder

So I tried getting this app on my Imac.
https://github.com/snobu/destreamer
I follwoed the instructions and did this in apple's terminal app
git clone https://github.com/snobu/destreamer

$ cd destreamer

$ npm install

$ npm run build

now the problem is that I can't find the destreamer folder in "Finder". If I use the terminal and do "cd destreamer" it executes it but I still can't find the path on my mac

I'm not familiar with cloning and building git apps nor am I familiar with Mac os. any help would he appreciated

Comment: Type `pwd` when you are within the `destreamer` folder and it should tell you where exactly you are located. You may need to use [Finder’s “go to“ command](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/go-directly-to-a-specific-folder-on-mac-mchlp1236/mac) to open the path since it may be in a non-standard location.

Comment: In your terminal, type in `open .` to open the current folder in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal starts in your "Home" directory, which is typically the folder named after your current user.  For example, if my username is `JohnDoe`, Terminal will open the folder at `/Users/JohnDoe` as my "Home" Directory.

I bet that's where your file was saved.